# Java: Do I have an effective regex to eliminate symbols & rename a file?

Tags: java, regex

I have a series of link names from which I'm trying to eliminate special characters. From a brief filewalk, my biggest concerns appear to be brackets, parentheses and colons. After unsuccessfully wrestling with escape characters to SELECT `:` `[` and `(`, I decided instead to exclude everything I wanted to KEEP in the filename.

Consider:

```
String foo = inputFilname ;   //SAMPLE DATA: [Phone]_Michigan_billing_(automatic).html
String scrubbed foo = foo.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z-._]","") ;
```

Expected Result: `Phone_Michigan_billing_automatic.html`

My escape-character regex was approaching 60 characters when I ditched it. The last version I saved before changing strategies was `[:.(\\[)|(\\()|(\\))|(\\])]` where I *thought* I was asking for `escape-character-[()` and `]`.

The blanket exclude seems to work just fine. Is the Regex really that simple? Any input on how effective this strategy will be? I feel like I'm missing something and need a couple sets of eyes.

Comment: Show us what you tried before this one? How did you escaped those brackets?

Comment: There are only a few characters which are invalid in a file name. You might want to return to your strategy to only remove invalid ones rather than white-listing a (very limited) set of 'valid' ones. What was your problematic regular expression?

Comment: Keep in mind that, when using the 'character set' delimiters `[]`, most special characters no longer behave special, the big exceptions being `-`, `^`, and `]`.  If `-` is part of a character set, it must appear at the beginning or end.  For example, `[-aA]` is valid, but `[a-A]` is technically not, as it doesn't match the `-` character, but tries to form a range between a and A.  Similarly, `^` will only be used as a character in the set if it's not at the beginning.  Not sure if/how you can deal with `]`.

Comment: to escape the brackets, I used all kinds of combinations of `\\]`. I was able to get it working on a single character, butonce I started looking for two or more characters, nothing. I was trying parens to delineate 'these three characters are an escape and a character' with `|` (or) with no luck.

Comment: In Java regex, you can also use `\Q` and `\E` to escape everything between them.

Comment: @KenoguLabz closing brackets were problematic. Once I did a mass exclude with `^a-zA-Z` brackets were selected and replaced. So tell me this: with my regex `[^a-zA-Z-._]`, I think I'm asking for everything EXCEPT: lowercase alpha, uppercase alpha, dash, period and underscore. I see what you're saying about the dash being a special character...can I esacpe to it in this scenario?

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann - is this something specific to Java? I'm testing with an online regex tester (javapal.com), and THAT is not recognizing `\E` as 'cancel escape'

Comment: I know it works in Java :) http://fiddle.re/a5zu

Comment: According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#qe it works with "the JGsoft engine, Perl, PCRE and Java".

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann - Guess what? I just switched over to RegexPlanet...significantly more comprehensive of a testing site. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you're using the wrong tool for this job.  [StringUtils has a method named replaceChars](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceChars%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that will replace all occurrences of a char with another one.  Here's the documentation:

```
public static String replaceChars(String str,
                              String searchChars,
                              String replaceChars)

Replaces multiple characters in a String in one go. This method can also be used to delete characters.

For example:
replaceChars("hello", "ho", "jy") = jelly.

A null string input returns null. An empty ("") string input returns an empty string. A null or empty set of search characters returns the input string.

The length of the search characters should normally equal the length of the replace characters. If the search characters is longer, then the extra search characters are deleted. If the search characters is shorter, then the extra replace characters are ignored.

 StringUtils.replaceChars(null, *, *)           = null
 StringUtils.replaceChars("", *, *)             = ""
 StringUtils.replaceChars("abc", null, *)       = "abc"
 StringUtils.replaceChars("abc", "", *)         = "abc"
 StringUtils.replaceChars("abc", "b", null)     = "ac"
 StringUtils.replaceChars("abc", "b", "")       = "ac"
 StringUtils.replaceChars("abcba", "bc", "yz")  = "ayzya"
 StringUtils.replaceChars("abcba", "bc", "y")   = "ayya"
 StringUtils.replaceChars("abcba", "bc", "yzx") = "ayzya"
```

So in your example:

```
    String translated = StringUtils.replaceChars("[Phone]_Michigan_billing_(automatic).html", "[]():", null);
    System.out.println(translated);
```

Will output:

> Phone_Michigan_billing_automatic.html

This will be more straightforward and easier to understand than any regex you could write.

Comment: I think what you end up with here is quite complicated to replace a straight forward regex.

Comment: You mean that one line that says exactly what it's doing in plain english (ie: `replaceChars`)?

Comment: I mean supplying a (potentially incomplete) list of chars to be replaced rather than the regex white list.

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex can be as simple as `\W` which will match everything that is not a word character (letters, digits, and underscores). This is the negation of `\w`

So your code becomes:

```
foo.replaceAll("\W","");
```

**As pointed out in the comments the above also removes periods this will work to also keep periods:**

```
foo.replaceAll("[^\w.]","");
```

Details: escape every thing that is **not** (the `^` inside the character class), **a digit, underscore, letter** ( the `\w`) or **a period** (the `\.`)

As noted above there may be other chars you want to white list: like `-`. Just include them in your character class as you go along.

```
foo.replaceAll("[^\w.\-]","");
```

Comment: Won't that remove "_" and "."?

Comment: It will defiantly keep the underscore, I am not one hundred percent sure on the . - need to go look that up.

Comment: @tieTYT You are correct - need to add the period. The underscore is covered/negated by the \W - \w. Fixed now.

Comment: Tweaked with @nhahtdh 's input.

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex is the way to go. In general white listing values instead of black listing them is almost always better.(Only allowing characters you KNOW are good instead of eliminating all characters you think are bad)  From a security standpoint this regex should be preferred. You will never end up with a inputFilename which has invalid characters.

```
suggested regex: [^a-zA-Z-._]
```

Comment: You missed the escape on your `.`. This should be `^a-zA-Z-\._`

Comment: @Matthew: No need for that. I need to check about `-`, though... Well, it seems OK in this case, but I'd go on the safe side and put `-` at the end...

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for the refresher there - had forgotten that was not the case inside a character class. You are also correct on the hyphen (`-`). It does need to be escaped.